# Page ViewState, Control ViewState and ControlState

Tags: asp.net, .net, viewstate

What is the difference between Page ViewState, Control ViewState and ControlState? Why there are 3 different things in ASP.Net?

Comment: Try to google these type of questions....

Comment: @AbdulRahmanAnsari I have tried... but not getting any satisfactory answer :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Page is a `Control`, so inherits the `ViewState` property.  When ViewState is saved, ASP.NET iterates over the control tree, persisting each Control's ViewState to a persistence medium (by default a hidden field in the rendered HTML).

`ViewState` incurs an overhead, which can be expensive, especially for data-bound controls such as `Repeater`, `DataGrid` etc.  It is therefore often desirable to disable ViewState, and instead regenerate the control on each postback.

However in .NET 1.x this caused problems, as some controls did not work properly when ViewState was disabled - examples are paging and sorting in a `DataGrid`.

`ControlState` was therefore introduced in .NET 2 to enable controls to save the minimal state data they need to function on postback.

Answer (score 1):

- `View state` is the method that the ASP.NET page framework uses to
  preserve page and control values between round trips. When the HTML
  markup for the page is rendered, the current state of the page and
  values that must be retained during postback are serialized into
  base64-encoded strings. This information is then put into the view
  state hidden field or fields.

[**Link 1**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[**Link 2**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)

- `Control state`, introduced in ASP.NET version 2.0, is similar to
  `view state` but functionally independent of `view state`. A page
  developer can disable `view state` for the page or for an individual
  control for performance. However, `control state` cannot be disabled.
  `Control state` is designed for storing a control's essential data
  (such as a pager control's page number) that must be available on
  postback to enable the control to function even when `view state` has
  been disabled.

[**Link 1**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1whwt1k7.aspx)

- `Control ViewState` Gets a dictionary of state information that
  allows you to save and restore the view state of a server control
  across multiple requests for the same page.

[**Link 1**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Hope this helps somewhat